# is any way to make sublime bind one single key

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use sublime text 3, it's a great tool, as I know sublime can easily bind a combined key (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), but if I only one bind like `\` key, is that possible?
and I have tried to make the config to the keymap file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to assign key bindings to single keys. In your case, since the `\` symbol escapes the symbol following it (for example, `\n` is the escape sequence for a newline), you need to escape it with another `\`:

```json
{ "keys": ["\\"], "command": "my_command" }
```

This will bind the command `my_command` to the <kbd>\</kbd> key.